# Customize welcome bot in telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to give different welcome messages to to new members who join the telegram group in the different time(morning / overnight), so I fixed a bit of code of telegram welcome bot but it didn't properly work

welcome_morning = 9am - 11pm 
welcome_overnight = 11pm - 9am

I think main problem is the indentation,but I'm not sure.

Can you teach me what's wrong with the code and make this work?

Thank you

```
def welcome_morning(update, context, new_member):

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if 9 <= now.hour <= 23:

        message = update.message
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        logger.info(
            "%s joined to chat %d (%s)",
            escape(new_member.first_name),
            chat_id,
            escape(message.chat.title),
        )

        # Pull the custom message for this chat from the database
        text = db.get(str(chat_id))

    # Use default message if there's no custom one set

    if text is None:
        text = 'text for new member in the morning'

    # Replace placeholders and send message
    text = text.replace("$username", new_member.first_name)
    text = text.replace("$title", message.chat.title)
    send_async(context, chat_id=chat_id, text=text, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
```

```
def welcome_overnight(update, context, new_member):

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if 23 <= now.hour <= 9:

        message = update.message
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        logger.info(
            "%s joined to chat %d (%s)",
            escape(new_member.first_name),
            chat_id,
            escape(message.chat.title),
        )

        # Pull the custom message for this chat from the database
        text = db.get(str(chat_id))

        # Use default message if there's no custom one set
        
    if text is None:
        text = text for new member in the night

    # Replace placeholders and send message
    text = text.replace("$username", new_member.first_name)
    text = text.replace("$title", message.chat.title)
    send_async(context, chat_id=chat_id, text=text, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
```

Comment: What telegram module are you using? And why does your current code not work? Please post the traceback in your question. Also, are you sure the users of your bot are in the same timezone as you?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
def welcome(update, context, new_member):

    message = update.message
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    logger.info(
        "%s joined to chat %d (%s)",
        escape(new_member.first_name),
        chat_id,
        escape(message.chat.title),
    )

    # Pull the custom message for this chat from the database
    text = db.get(str(chat_id))

    
    # Use default message if there's no custom one set

    if text is None:
        if 9 <= now.hour <= 23:
            text = 'text for new member in the morning'
        else:
            text = 'text for new member in the night'
    
    # Replace placeholders and send message
    text = text.replace("$username", new_member.first_name)
    text = text.replace("$title", message.chat.title)
    send_async(context, chat_id=chat_id, text=text, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
```

In this way you have only a function that checks the time and set the correct custome welcome message (only if there is no custome one set).

Another suggestion could be replacing the `now=datetime.datetime.now()` with the date parameter inside the message object. But you should convert it to datetime object.

```
now = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(message.date)
```